# Getting the Value of a Number using this in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I want to add the a "roundTo" function to the existing Number Object in Javascript. The function would return the number rounded to x decimals.
Here's a working function without using the number prototype:

```
Math.roundTo = (value, decimals) => Math.round(value * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / Math.pow(10, decimals);
```

But when I tried this:

```
Number.prototype.roundTo = decimals => this = Math.round(this * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / Math.pow(10, decimals);
```

There was an ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side.

So now, I want to know how to get the Value of the Number, because using the "this" keyword, i dont get the value of the Number.
But how do I get the Value of the Number?

Comment: That's the problem with everyone using arrow function, you lose the scoped `this`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to use a normal function, because when using an arrow function you lose the `this`.

Second you have to return the value not change `this`, because that's a readonly reference.

```js
Number.prototype.roundTo = function(decimals) {
  return Math.round(this * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / Math.pow(10, decimals);
}

let x = 5.1234;

console.log(x.roundTo(1));
```

And if you already have your method implemented on `Math`, you can use:

```js
Math.roundTo = (value, decimals) => Math.round(value * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / Math.pow(10, decimals);

Number.prototype.roundTo = function(decimals) {
  return Math.roundTo(this, decimals);
}

let x = 5.1234;

console.log(x.roundTo(1));
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer and it solved my problem! :) But do you know a way when calling the "roundTo" function, you immediately set the value of the Number to the rounded value?

Comment: just use `x=x.roundTo(n)`

Comment: I understand that this will work too, but i wonder if it's possible to call the function and then x is set to the rounded value?    `let x = 5.1234;  x.roundTo(2);`   and now x = 5.12

Comment: @byJames like this? `let x = 5.1234.roundTo(2)`

Comment: @adiga yes, but imagine i have the variable x already, so i can call `x.roundTo(n)` and x is rounded now without having to use `x = x.roundTo(n)`

Comment: @byJames numbers and strings are immutable. `x.roundTo(n)` doesn't change `x`. Just like `someString.replace('1', '')` doesn't update the original string. You have to reassign to change their value.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` variable is not available in an arrow function scope. You'll need a conventional function declaration for that.

The reason that you get the error is that you cannot assign to `this`. It is a readonly variable that refers to the (`Number`) object itself. You probably want to return the wanted value instead:

```
Number.prototype.roundTo = function(decimals) {return Math.round(this * Math.pow(10, decimals)) / Math.pow(10, decimals);};
```

used like

```
1.234567.roundTo(2);
```

Comment: You can directly use like this: `1.234567.roundTo(2)`